# setting animation on button in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, css-transitions

Hey guys i have a button component in my react project so let me show code

```
class Button extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      active: false,
    };
  }    

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className={
          this.state.active
            ?  "thankyou_button_active":"thankyou_button"

        }
        onClick={() =>
          this.setState({ active: !this.state.active })
        }
      >
        Thank you!
      </button>
    );


  }
}
```

.css

```
.thankyou_button_active {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  background-color: #ff9d72;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ff9d72;
  width: 120px;
  outline: none;
  height: 31px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(4px);

}
.thankyou_button {
  border: 1px solid #ff9d72;
  background: white;
  color: #ff9d72;
  width: 120px;
  outline: none;
  height: 31px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

I am changing the class assigned to button on onClick event so initially my button state 'active' is false so class assigned is 'thankyou_button' but after first click  class assigned is 'thankyou_button_active'

On this state of change i want is my button should have a pressed effect like go a little upwards/downwards in y axis and come back down to original position.... with this css button goes down as i have mentioned in 'thankyou_button_active' class but doesnt comes up cause that class still remains active until next click

Comment: Can you please add css for this file. It would be helpful to slove this problem

Comment: Try adding this

Comment: thankyou_button {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

Comment: append transition to thnakyou_button

Comment: You should have a look at `styled components`. With styled components, you can customize a `button` and pass it some props, then you can modify its css based on the props

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `setTimeout` after `setState` to flip the state again, so the class will flip back to inactive (or normal class) after the animation ends, 
you need to add `transition: all 0.4s ease-in;` in `.thankyou_button` class too.

Working code:

React:

```
class Button extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      active: false,
    };
  }    

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className={
          this.state.active
            ?  "thankyou_button_active":"thankyou_button"

        }
        onClick={() =>
          this.setState({ active: !this.state.active })
          setTimeout(()=>{
            this.setState({ active: !this.state.active })
           },400)
        }
      >
        Thank you!
      </button>
    );


  }
}
```

css:

```
.thankyou_button_active {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  background-color: #ff9d72;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ff9d72;
  width: 120px;
  outline: none;
  height: 31px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(4px);

}
.thankyou_button {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  border: 1px solid #ff9d72;
  background: white;
  color: #ff9d72;
  width: 120px;
  outline: none;
  height: 31px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

pen:
https://codepen.io/davsugi/pen/dyYvOME?editors=0111